# Java profiler for Mac OS X which supports marking the heap

Tags: java, macos, profiler

I want to know the number of extra objects created by processing a single request in my application.

I remember that OptimizeIt used to be able to do it. The steps, as I remember it were:

1. Attach profiler to the application
2. Run a small load on the server, so that all initialization activities happen
3. "Force GC" from the profiler, which runs a full GC
4. "Mark heap", so now we know the number of instances of each type in the heap
5. Send one request to the server.
6. The profiler shows what objects were created since the last "mark"
7. "Force GC" again to see if any objects are lingering

OptimizeIt does not seem to be actively developed anymore (please correct me if I am wrong), and it does not seem to support Mac OS X.

Are there any other Java profilers for Mac OS X which support the scenario I outlined above?

Answer (score 1):

[JProfiler](http://ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) can do that. You

1. Attach to the running application
2. Start recording allocations
3. Perform your use case
4. Take a heap snapshot and check "Select recorded objects" in the heap walker options dialog

Then the initial object set of the heap walker will only contain the strongly referenced objects that have been created by your use case.

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler

Answer (score 0):

Take a peek at [JVisualVM](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) from Sun/Oracle. In its base configuration, I don't think it does what you need, but it has a number of plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Memory sampler](http://java.dzone.com/announcements/visualvm-12-great-java) from VisualVM and use it in 'Deltas' mode.